# How to fix angular reactive forms ( form.value ) throwing eslint typedef error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, angular-reactive-forms

I have a formGroup and have initialized as below. However when I try to get the whole form value via `form.value`  it gives me an eslint typecast error

```ts
userForm = new FormGroup<user>({
    name: new FormControl<string>('first', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]),
    age: new FormControl<number>('25', Validators.required),
    gender: new FormControl<string>('male'),
    profile: new FormControl<string>(this.profiles[1].shortName),
});

//getting value from below

this.userForm.value `
```

```
error: expect userForm.value to have a type annotation.          @typescript-eslint/@typedef
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What type do you expect `userForm.value` to be?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct use is:

```
 userForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('first', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]),
        age: new FormControl(25, Validators.required),
        gender: new FormControl('male'),
        profile: new FormControl(this.profiles[1]?.shortName),
    });
    
    // getting value from below
    this.userForm.value;
```